# Where is knitr cached output stored?

Tags: r, knitr

In the cache directory, one can use `lazyLoad` to view the environment at the end of a chunk. But where is the output of the chunk (that will be printed if the document is compiled) stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the source!

Look at the source code here `https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/cache.R`

You can see that the mechanism is explained here (within the `new_cache` function)

```
# when cache=3, code output is stored in .[hash], so cache=TRUE won't lose
# output as cacheSweave does; for cache=1,2, output is the evaluate() list
cache_output = function(hash, mode = 'character') {
  get(sprintf('.%s', hash), envir = knit_global(), mode = mode, inherits = FALSE)
}
```

I.e. it is stored as an object in the `knit_global` environemnt`

You can inspect these objects by `ls(knitr::knit_global(), all = TRUE)`

I.e. the 3 simple chunks below

````
```{r, cache=TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

```{r }
 ls(knitr::knit_global(), all = TRUE)

```


```{r }
 get(ls(knitr::knit_global(), all = TRUE)[1], knitr::knit_global())

```
````

Give following output

````
summary(cars)
##      speed           dist    
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 43  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120
 ls(knitr::knit_global(), all = TRUE)
## [1] ".Preview-2b40490e2591_cache/unnamed-chunk-1_766fcb86fd875984b372e3c23210bfad"
## [2] "metadata"
 get(ls(knitr::knit_global(), all = TRUE)[1], knitr::knit_global())
## [1] "\n```r\nsummary(cars)\n```\n\n```\n##      speed           dist    \n##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2  \n##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26  \n##  Median :15.0   Median : 36  \n##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 43  \n##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56  \n##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120\n```"
````

If you have exited R, you can load the data from the file *.RData in the cache folder using the `load` command. Also, to output the result of `get`, consider to use `cat` which will turn the "\n" into lines and should look like original output.

Comment: Thanks mnel! Great example. I will make two additions (I'll try to edit) I hope you don't mind: (1) add info on how to load the RData from the folder. And (2) to `cat` the return of `get`.