# How can I modify how knitr cache is stored and loaded?

Tags: r, caching, r-markdown, knitr

when I knit a document with cache = TRUE, I often find that re-kniting is not much faster.
I am wondering if the actual cached files are stored on disk in a less than optimal format and loaded back 'slowly' as well.
I see in [Where is knitr cached output stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721859/where-is-knitr-cached-output-stored) a reference to https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/cache.R where I think objects are stored and loaded as R data file and not stored in RAM.
Questions are then:

- am I right?
- is there an approved way of modifying this, I'd like to use say the [qs](https://github.com/traversc/qs) format that allow multithreaded save and load
- best would be to simply save the objects in a different environment, and access them on demand, is this doable?

Comment: Knitting is designed to be done in a separate R process, so storing in RAM would not be possible.  You can knit in the same process, but you lose reproducibility.

Comment: That's fine with me, the best workflow is to start knitting in another process at the very end of the work anyway (for final rendering), which is typically what happens in a notebook (jupyter-like)

Answer (score 2):

As shown in your link to `knitr/R/cache.R`, `knitr` sets up a list of functions to manage the cache and stores it in the unexported `knitr:::cache` object.  That object is a list of functions; those functions share as their environment the evaluation frame from when `new_cache()` was called.

If you wanted to change the location where cached objects were stored, or the method used to store them, you could modify the `knitr:::cache` object.

This is a little tricky, because it's not an exported object.  But here's how to do it:

```
newcache <- knitr:::cache

#  Make all the changes you like to newcache!

assignInNamespace("cache", newcache, "knitr")
```

For example, this document prints some info about calls to `exists` in the rendering log:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2022-07-29"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache = TRUE)

newcache <- knitr:::cache
oldexists <- newcache$exists
newcache$exists <- function(hash, lazy = TRUE) {
  cat("cache$exists called with hash=", hash, "\n")
  oldexists(hash, lazy)
}
assignInNamespace("cache", newcache, "knitr")
```


```{r}
x <- 1:100
print(x[1:10])
```
````

I saw this in the log before the usual call to Pandoc:

```
processing file: Untitled.Rmd
  |..................                                                    |  25%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................................                                   |  50%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |....................................................                  |  75%
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
cache$exists called with hash= Untitled_cache/html/unnamed-chunk-1_bc684450204aad4eef880fd842708be8 
cache$exists called with hash= Untitled_cache/html/unnamed-chunk-1_bc684450204aad4eef880fd842708be8
```